# Small player appears in top-left corner before BigVideo.js loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I am trying to implement [BigVideo.js](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) as the background-video behind a centered container in a Bootstrap 3.0.3-website.

The sample-video is correctly playing, however, when the page is loading, a small player appears in the top-left corner, before the video finally plays:

[image]

If you check out [this example](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-ambient-loop.html) in Firefox, you can see the distribution of the loading animation.

I would like that this loading animation is centered and spans the whole background, before showing content and video. [This issue was reported before on GitHub](https://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js/issues/65), however, without providing a satisfying, working solution.

Unfortunately, my JavaScript-knowledge is very limited. I already implemented [PreLoadMe.js](http://niklausgerber.com/blog/preloadme-a-lightweight-jquery-website-preloader/) to hide the loading process of BigVideo.js, but unfortunately the background video starts to load when PreLoadMe.js has finished. So the same effect takes place.

I currently call the BigVideo-function in the following way, as described on the support site:

```
<!-- BigVideo -->

<script>
$(function() {
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
BV.init();
BV.show('http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4', {ambient:true});
});
</script>

<!-- Preloader -->

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
        $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
        $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    })
//]]>
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
<div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="container">


  <div class="content-box" >
    <h1>Ipsum Lorum</h1>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body { 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.content-box {

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    color: white;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    z-index: 2;

    padding: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: -200px 0 0 -200px;  
}


#preloader {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#fff; /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
    z-index:99; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

#status {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-image:url(../img/status.gif); /* path to your loading animation */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; /* is width and height divided by two */
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a solution that worked for me :

**CSS :**

```
#big-video-wrap {
    display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT** :

```
BV.getPlayer().on('durationchange',function(){
    $('#big-video-wrap').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: If you hide #big-video-wrap, you hide the complete background video.

Comment: In my case, that was the point. Hiding the complete video background until the video is fully loaded and ready to be played.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an HTML/CSS only solution to get it to a base "centered" point, and then use Javascript to finalize the details. Set html/body to 100% height and then horizontally center your loading animation, and give it a top margin of like 100px so you know that on all devices and in all browsers, even without JS, you'll have it visible and centered. Period. Then, center it vertically using javascript. I see you have it fixed, which is fine, that just means you'll have to figure out how to position it a bit better using that method. Keep in mind that certain android devices have a fixed position bug where fixed elements go absolutely nuts, so unless you're ready to deal with that I'd just take the other approach.

The background of your HTML element or body element should be #000 to match the loader.
That's what I'd do- you have a progressively enhancing loader in this case :)

Also, I would clip your loading graphic down to just the loader. I'm not sure why you have that extra space around it, but it's unnecessary. If you want the whole background black you can do what I mentioned above (#000 on body background), or if you want that black area around it like you have it now, you can wrap it in a div that has those dimensions with a #000 bg and center that. This is a good paradigm for reducing your pageload times- clip all unnecessary stuff, particularly when you can do it with CSS.

Comment: The problem is that the generic preloader of BigVideo.js is not loading in the full page (see image). I used #Preloader-div to hide the generic loading process of BigVideo.js, which does not work. The loading process of BigVideo just starts afterwards. So the question is: How to fix the BigVideo.js preloader without using an extra preloader-plugin? Like here: http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-ambient-loop.html By the way if you try this link in Firefox, you will see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue to use the pre-loader, you might be able to use the videojs ready event as a trigger instead of the page load to fade everything out. Something along these lines:

```
videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){
    $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
});
```

See here for more information: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/api.md

Comment: The preloader is now continuously loading and not going to the main content. The following Javascript doesn't seem to do the trick: http://jsbin.com/aPeFiPo/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your style put:

```
.vjs-control-bar {
display: none;}
```